# How to find number of subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

I have a Xcode project and in it i have dragged two views and both of them inherit from a class LabelsView. However when I try and run the code to find out number of subviews, I get 4. Can anyone explain why is this happening.
The code is

```
NSLog(@"no. of subviews:%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.superview.subviews count]]);
```

Comment: I would guess it's because there are 4 subviews.

Comment: Try printing the subview array out and examining what's in there.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably getting a weird subview count because you're accessing self.superview.subviews.  You likely just want self.subviews.

If, like you said, you only care about subviews of type LabelsView, you can filter those out like this:

```
int labelViewCount = 0;
for(LabelsView *subview in self.subviews) {

    if([subview isKindOfClass:[LabelsView class]]) {
         labelViewCount++;
    }
}
NSLOG(@"label count: %d", labelViewCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the amount of all subviews in swift, you can just go with

```swift
self.subviews.count
```